# Largest Rectangle in Histogram. Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to do the following problem, linked here:

https://leetcode.com/problems/largest-rectangle-in-histogram/

The code I have right now is always off by one or two. Additionally, it is too slow to run (getting the Time Limit Exceeded Error) on their website.

My code is pasted below. Can somebody see where the error might be, and how I can improve the **existing** code to make it work?

```
class Solution(object):
def largestRectangleArea(self, height):
    """
    :type height: List[int]
    :rtype: int
    """
    dic = {}
    #secondList is for storing deleted items.
    secondList = []
    if not height:
        return 0
    #stores the max rectangle strting from 'key', a height.
    for index in range(len(height)):
        num = height[index]

        for entry in dic:
            if num >= entry[0]:
                dic[entry] += entry[0]
            else:
                #if num is less than it
                secondList.append(dic[entry])


                dic[(num ,entry[1])]  = (index+1-entry[1])*num
                del dic[entry]
        dic[(num, index)] = num
    if secondList:
        secondList = max(secondList)
    return max(max([dic[i] for i in dic]), secondList)
```

Comment: you say you want to fix your code. In case you want a [spanking-new implementation](http://www.pastebin.com/YXbnnNBq), for fun I have just tried to solve the problem. BTW it returns 24 on [2,2,5,1,3,4,2,12,2,2,5,5,5,6,3,2]

Comment: @Pynchia: I don't quite understand your code. Can you add some explanation?

Comment: hello, it's quite easy: the idea is, for every element in the sequence, to examine each following element (including the present one) and check if the value is higher or not. If not, then the height is decreased to match the maximum height the rectangle can have. At every step I keep track of the width of the rectangle and I return each and every rectangle. If you find it hard to understand `enumerate` and `yield`, please look them up on SO and Google